# cURL timeout when calling HTTPS page with old certs

Tags: php, drupal, curl, https, libcurl

I am trying to get the XML from a Data Service at my institution using PHP and cURL (libcurl). The development is being done on my local machine. It is code that is eval'd in PHP as part of Drupal and the Transformations module.

It has SSL support as shown from running:

`$curl-config --features` *(from [libcurl docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html))*

> SSL
>   IPv6
>   libz
>   NTLM

The PHP code being executed:

```
/**
 * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
 * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
 * FROM: http://bit.ly/lNIlOu
 */
function get_web_page( $url )
{
  $agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30';
  //$agent = 'spider';

  $options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page if successful
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $agent, // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,    // Disable host checks ?
  );

  $ch      = curl_init( $url );
  curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
  $content = curl_exec( $ch );
  $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
  $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
  $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  $header['errno']   = $err;
  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  $header['content'] = $content;
  return $header;
}

$url = 'https://ws.admin.washington.edu/student/v4/public/section.xml?year=2011&quarter=autumn&curriculum_abbreviation=BIOL&course_number=&id=&search_by=Instructor';
$result = get_web_page($url);

echo '<pre>CURL result:<br/>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

A slimmed down version of dumping $ch:

```
array(24) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(155) "https://ws.admin.washington.edu/student/v4/public/section.xml?year=2011&quarter=autumn&curriculum_abbreviation=BIOL&course_number=&id=&search_by=Instructor"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(237)
  ...
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(20)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(120.41427)
  ...
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.11626)
  ...
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["errno"]=>
  int(28)
  ["errmsg"]=>
  string(67) "Operation timed out after 120000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"
  ["content"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

When I visit the site myself it simply loads. I even set the agent signature to be the exact same as my own.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's quite bizarre that it's not working for you. I copied the code above and ran it through the command line (on a Mac) and it worked like a charm. Trying adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` and see if the additional information is helpful in any way.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. Im using this as part of a module in Drupal and that might be the reason, something in the module or in drupal might have changed the cURL settings but since I am creating my own instance of it I don't understand. Will add this to my post as well and try adding what you gave me.

Comment: Actually simply running it on it's own outside of Drupal surfaces the same problem. Now I have no clue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the verbose setting above?

Comment: Works from my terminal as well. Had to add the `--insecure` option though.

Comment: Could it be a Mac OS X firewall issue?

Comment: @FD, verbose didn't add any new information to the error. But thanks!

Comment: @AL, I'm not able to find how to set the `--insecure` option from within the PHP above.

Comment: Actually `--insecure` does the same as `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` according to the libcurl docs (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)

Comment: @FD, no firewall installed ;(

Answer (score 1):

For me adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` magically solved the issue!

Comment: This is at the mom a very common problem. The default SSL Version is set to 2 but its not more supported in the openssl module. I had the same problem and search a lot to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works now when I upload it to my server. I was trying this from my Mac OSX 10.6.7 which seems to block port 443 commonly used for the HTTPS protocol. I could not find a way to open it up or find out why it was blocked.

But my script works fine **outside of my local machine**.

Thanks for you help so far.