# How do I get XML from a HTTPS connection without cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have had two days of [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566772/curl-timeout-when-calling-https-page-with-old-certs) getting anything done with cURL. Is there another way to get the contents of a page on a HTTPS connection in PHP?

Comment: The useless one-liners below are correct if your php version has openssl compiled in. In any case you should investigate one of the HTTP utility classes (PEAR HTTP_Request2 or the Zend thingy), which either utilizes a raw socket connection over ssl, or wraps around cURL with a nicer API. If your PHP version is more contemporary you might even have the http://php.net/http extension compiled in or available.

Comment: Thanks! I checked out HTTP request and even another PECL lib for HTTP requests _but_ both of them require some installations and server configuration that I am not used to. The effort I have time to put into this project is very small.

Comment: You should post your code / example. Maybe there is something to debug with that. Maybe it's not a library problem, but a plain user-agent block. Otherwise try the `wget` or `curl` commandline tools as last resort.

Comment: Thanks mario, I actually just figured out the problem. It is problably the firewall at home. I tried it on one of my web server outside home it works nicely. Thanks everyone for answering the actual question that I asked though :)

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents` (i.e. stream wrappers)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't solve my problem. Maybe they are both working and my problem is something else.

Comment: This answer is not about your problem, but about your question. Your question was: "Is there another way to get the contents of a page on a HTTPS connection in PHP than curl?"

Comment: True, there is always a dilemma wether to answer the persons question as it was asked or the problem behind it which is the reason for the question. +1 for the answer you gave me since I didn't specify anything else.

Answer (score 1):

`fsockopen()` [perhaps?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)